# smiley with text message to be displayed in list view

Tags: android, chat, message

How can i display smiley along with text message in listview. I am developing chat screen.i type message and i need to add smileys along with text. When i press enter button i need to display text and smiley in the above list view where i display list of messages. Please guide me in this.

some thing like Gtalk chat where we type message and we have an option to select smiley. when we select smiley corresponding special charcter will be displayed. I am able to show grid with smileys and when i select smiley i am able to display specialchatcter(statically) using the position of the smiley.

how can i display these special character and smileys from database. I am i need of help in this issue. Please guide me.

Thanks.

Regards,
Raghav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you used grid view for all smiley..you refer this [**this link see with multiple images**](http://androidbysravan.blogspot.com/2011/02/displaying-multiple-images-using.html)

Comment: This is what i needed. Chat application to display smileys with text.. This is the best link :http://dipakkeshariyainandroid.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-add-smileyemojis-in-edittext.html .Thanks a lot to the author.

Comment: hello link is not working please update it :dipakkeshariyainandroid.blogspot.com/2011/08/…

Answer (score 1):

Use [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html) if you want to display text and images.